# How to completely delete iOS app installed via Xcode from mac?

Tags: ios, xcode

I ran my iOS on my mac but now I want to delete it including app bundle. How I can perform it? Where is app bundle stored?

I've tried `po Bundle.main.bundleUrl` but it leads to wrong folder which is mounted drive and disappears immediately after unloading app.

Comment: Just delete it the exact same way as you'd delete any other app installed from the AppStore. All application data, including the bundle are removed this way.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. I tried to delete app this way but after deleting and relaunching I still logged in and have got all cached data.

Comment: @Grigorii i also have this issue, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This data is stored under `~/Library/Containers/`. Note that when building form Xcode you get a random UUID as the container name, instead of the reverse DNS you'd expect normally, e.g. `69A9F3A1-64D7-4EA9-96FE-8C81441060FF`.

I couldn't find a way to determine which one is your app except for printing a file path inside the app and seeing the prefix, which can be done in lldb like so:

```
(lldb) po FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
```

(Depending on when you pause execution you might need to do this instead:)

```
(lldb) e -l Swift -- import Foundation
(lldb) e -l Swift -O -- FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
```

Or extrapolating from the modification date of the containers with these type of names, if there aren't too many.

Comment: If you go to `~/Library/Containers/` in Finder and it will translate all the names so you can find your application to delete.